# Double series $\sum_{n,m}a_{n,m}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a doubt about the double series that I'm studying now for the first time.

Let us consider the double series
$$\sum_{n,m}a_{n,m}, \ \ \text{where}\ n,m\in\mathbb Z\ \text{and}\ a_{n,m}\in\mathbb C.$$
If $a_{n,m}=b_{n,m}\cdot k_{n,m}$, where $b_{n,m}, k_{n,m}\in\mathbb C$, and $|k_{n,m}|\leq M$ with $M>0$, can we state that: $\left|\sum_{n,m}a_{n,m}\right|\leq M \left|\sum_{n,m}b_{n,m}\right|$?

Comment: Yes. Use triangle inequality and then replace $k_{m,n}$ by $M$

Comment: Sure? I'm not quite convinced. Certainly $\left|\sum_{n,m}a_{n,m}\right|\leq M \sum_{n,m}|b_{n,m}|$ but I do not know if $\left|\sum_{n,m}a_{n,m}\right|\leq M \left|\sum_{n,m}b_{n,m}\right|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that it is a double series has nothing to to do with the question. What you are asking is whether
$$
\Bigl|\sum_{i\in I}b_i\,k_i\Bigr|\le\sup_{i\in I}|k_i|\,\Bigr|\sum_{i\in I}b_i\Bigl|
$$
where $I$ is a set of indexes (in your question $I=\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$.) The answer is no, since you can have $\sum_{i\in I}b_i=0$ but $\sum_{i\in I}b_i\,k_i\ne0$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I now understood.